# Jquery animation repeating code

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have made code but I want it to be execute repeatedly till the user is on the page.

Here is my code---

```
                   $(document).ready(

                     function animate() {
                          $('div.lightining').stop().animate({
                            backgroundColor: '#789'
                          }, 1050, 'linear', function() { });
                     }

                     function () { $('div.lightining').cycle(animate()); }

                   );
```

I want that the script to repeat itself after getting completed.
Does someone get any ideas of achieving this. Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           $(document).ready( function() {


             function animate() {
                  $('div.lightining').stop().animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#789'
                  }, 1050, 'linear', function() {  animate(); });
             }

           animate();

           });
```

Comment: sorry but it seems that you doesn't got my question. Sorry, because it's my fault. Anyways, I want the the script repeat itself after it gets completed.

Comment: that is exactly what it is, Michael answered your question right. It has a callback which makes the function recursive.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code with some adjustments and it worked! Thanks a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the code below will loop an animation continuously
where

attribute is the attribute to animate

value the value to animate to

and duration the duration.

set these to whatever you want.

once the animation is complete the callback calls the animation again.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    animate();

});

function animate(){

    $(".lightning").animate({
        attribute:value
    },duration,function(){
        animate();
    });

}
```

not sure what you mean about the on the page part. you will have to clarify there.
also if im correct, you cant animate background colour without a plugin.

Comment: Ok I got you. Your code helped me to work out with the Michaels code. Thanks a lot!