# Timed text swap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swap, timed

is it possible to swap a paragraph of text with javascript/jQuery? 
I want a delay timer of about 5 seconds, and then the text should swap to something else, like a image slide. Would be awesome with a fade or an effect, but whatever works. Can you please point me in the right direction or help me out?

Comment: What mark-up are you working with? What have you tried already? What happened, or went wrong? What part(s) are you stuck on?

Comment: Anything here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+animate+delay

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery animation repeating code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311972/jquery-animation-repeating-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to loop without setTimeout or setInterval

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bWD4V/)

```
<div id="textMessage"></div>
<div class="textContent" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="textContent" style="display:none">In sit amet diam et arcu aliquam tincidunt. </div>

function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut('slow',
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
$(document).ready(function() {
  // save the texts in an array for re-use
  $(".textContent").each(function() {
    texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
  });
  slide()  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#target').html('New Text');
}, 5000); // <- 5 seconds
```

and if you want to take it further

```
setInterval(function() {
  // do some change that will happen every 5 seconds
}, 5000); // <- 5 seconds
```

Comment: and why not delay and/or animate?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this code, and yes. I want it to loop, so that code was good.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter but often for something this simple I prefer the setTimeout/setInterval because it reads a little more clear to me.  But as far as overhead and/or other benefits I cannot think of any

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/)

You can call the function with setTimeout as well

**Edit**:

[Here is the tweaked demo, without a click and with interval](http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/1)

**Edit 2**:

Copy pasted the code here in case jsfiddle goes down.

```
<div class="texts">
  <p class="text text_1">text 1</p>
  <p class="text text_2">text 2</p>  
</div>

<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    var toggle = $(".text").hasClass("toggled");
    $(".text_1").animate({opacity: toggle ? 1 : 0});
    $(".text_2").animate({opacity: toggle ? 0 : 1});
    $(".text").toggleClass("toggled");
  }, 1000);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.texts {
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.text_1{
    opacity: 1
}

.text_2{
   opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why not add a callback to make it loop and onload so not click is needed?

Comment: Yeah, how would you do that exactly? I want it to loop every 5 second without a click.

Comment: I can't get this to work with a loop and without the button click, anyone know how to get this going?

Comment: There you go http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/1/  Tweak the timer to whatever you want. Now it's 1 second

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeText(){
     document.getElementById('my_div_id').innerHTML = 'text_to_display';
}
```

you can implement changetext to have an array of strings on which you iterate inside the next function:

```
function timingex( ){
    setTimeout("changeText()",5000);
}
```

Comment: avoid the eval:  `setTimeout(changeText,5000);`

Answer (score 0):

Put your content, that you want to fade in (we can name it `#box`), right on top of the `<p>`. Hide it with `display:none;`.
Then use for example:

```
function() {
    $("#box").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
}
```